# How to find the runtime using srtool

Tags: parachain

I'm using [srtool](https://github.com/paritytech/srtool) on this [repo](https://github.com/kabocha-network/parachain) with these command steps:

```
export RUSTC_VERSION=1.64.0; export PACKAGE=kabocha-runtime; alias srtool='docker run --rm -it -e PACKAGE=$PACKAGE -v $PWD:/build -v $TMPDIR/cargo:/cargo-home paritytech/srtool:$RUSTC_VERSION'
```

```
srtool build --package kabocha-runtime
```

output:

```
root@ubuntu-s-kabocha-01-1627404188468-s-2vcpu-4gb-intel-lon1-01:~/kabocha-parachain# srtool build -r ./runtime/kabocha-runtime --package kabocha-runtime
Found 1.64.0, we will be using paritytech/srtool:1.64.0 for the build
 Substrate Runtime Toolbox - srtool v0.9.23 
              - by Chevdor -
info: using existing install for '1.64.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: override toolchain for '/build' set to '1.64.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  1.64.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)

  Building kabocha as release using rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
⏳ That can take a little while, be patient... subsequent builds will be faster.
   Since you have to wait a little, you may want to learn more about Substrate runtimes:
   https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/architecture/
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
!!! The PACKAGE 'kabocha' does not match the crate name at 'runtime/kabocha'. Did you mean ''?
```

relevant error snippet:

```
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
!!! The PACKAGE 'kabocha' does not match the crate name at 'runtime/kabocha'. Did you mean ''?
```

Probably missing something obvious but could you show me how to access the correct directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `srtool-cli` expects the runtimes to be organised as it is done in the polkadot repo. This is hystorical and often does not match, this is why the `srtool-cli` lets you tell where the runtime is located.

Since you did not provide the information, as the error mentions, the `srtool-cli` expects your runtime to be at `runtime/kabocha` and that path does not exist.

To fix your issue, check out the output of the `srtool build --help` command. You will find the following flag:

```
 -r, --runtime-dir <RUNTIME_DIR>
            If your runtime is not in the standard location runtime/<chain_name> you can pass this
            args to help srtool find it [env: RUNTIME_DIR=]
```

You now have a way to tell `srtool` where to find the runtime and in your case that is:

```
srtool build --package kabocha-runtime --runtime-dir runtime
```

Comment: hi chevdor, ive tried these variations: `srtool build  --package kabocha-runtime -r  ./runtime/ `and also `srtool build  -r  ./runtime/  --package kabocha-runtime` and also `srtool build  --package kabocha-runtime -r  ./runtime/kabocha-runtime` as well as just `-r ./`  all of which provide same error message

Comment: I see you are using `srtool` direclty (ie the Docker image), while you could get it to work, I strongly recommend using the `srtool-cli` I mentioned, it makes things MUCH easier. You can find this tool here: https://github.com/chevdor/srtool-cli

It takes care of lots of the work you are doing with those ENV.
Make sure to remove your `srtool` alias after installing the `srtool-cli` since it is also called `srtool`.
With `srtool-cli` installed, the command I mentioned above it working fine on your repo and it will pass all the expected args to the srtool Docker image used in the background.

Comment: ok i think i need to unalias srtool, will give it a spin now.

Comment: one issue is that is cant find my local pallet, do i need to change the structure of the files?

Comment: i was not in the parent directory, now it should work